# Prove that a function is not differentiable because it's not continuous

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-verification

> Given:
>    $$g(x) = \frac{1}{x^2-2x}$$
>   and:
>   $$
> f(x) = \begin{cases}
> a \quad x \ge 2 \\
> b \quad x<2 \
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   such that $-1<a<0<b<1$ prove that the functions are not differentiable.

Is it correct to say that $g(x)$ is not continuous at $x=2$ therefore not differentiable there and for $f(x) the one-sided limits are not the same therefore it's also not continuous and not differentiable?

Comment: The function $g$ is not defined at the point 2, so it doesn't make sense to talk about continuity or discontinuity at that point. And yes if a function is not continuous at a point, then it is also not differentiable at that point.

Comment: @TheveryfluffyPanda thanks and the second one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$g (x)$ is not actually defined at $x=2$ so we can't ask about its continuity or derivative at that $x$ value. 
For $f (x)$ yes your reasoning is sound.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative or f(x) at x= a is **defined** to as $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)- f(a)}{h}$.  Since the denominator clearly goes to 0, the only way the derivative could exist is if the numerator goes to 0.  But $\lim_{h\to 0} f(x)- f(a)= 0$ is equivalent to $\lim_{h\to 0} f(x)= f(a)$ which is the **definition** of "f(x) is continuous at x= a".

Notice that being continuous at a is a *necessary* condition for having a derivative at x= a, not a *sufficient* condition.  The function f(x)= |x| is continuous at x= 0 but not differentiable there.

Comment: Are you saying that $f(x)$ is continuous at the $x=2$?

Comment: I'm not sure who this is directed to but no one has said that the f(x) defined in the original post is continuous at x= 2.  I said that **if** any generic function, f(x), is differentiable at any x= a **then** it is continuous there.  Of course neither of the functions, f or g, defined in the first post is continuous or differentiable at x= 2.